# In a 3 node Elasticsearch cluster, a search is distributed through all nodes?

Tags: elasticsearch

If I have 3 data nodes and perform a query with a lot of aggregations, this search is distributed through all cluster data nodes?

Or the Elasticsearch elects one node to query and aggregate the data? Acting as a load balancer and not as like a "distributed map/reduce"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the index you're querying contains more than one shard (whether primary or replica), then those shards will be located on different nodes, hence the query will be distributed to each node that hosts a shard of the index you're querying.

One data node will receive your request and act as the coordinating node. It will check the cluster state to figure out where the shards are located, then it will forward the request to each node hosting a shard, gather the results and send them back to the client.

Comment: ok. I don't how elasticsearch works internally, but it is safe to assume that the documents are spread across the shards and the search will make all data nodes perform the same query and aggregations and return the result to the coordinating node in order to build the response?

Comment: Yes, definitely, this is how ES is supposed to work.